# Drawing an error ellipse in javascript with d3 and numericjs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, computer-vision, data-analysis, jstat

I'm attempting to implement [this](http://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/draw-error-ellipse-representing-covariance-matrix/) method for drawing covariance error ellipses in javascript.

```
errorEllipse = function(stdDevX, stdDevY, cor, center, level) {
  var errEllipse,
  cov = cor * stdDevX * stdDevY,
  covmat = [
  [stdDevX * stdDevX, cov],
  [cov, stdDevY * stdDevY]
  ],
  eig = numeric.eig(covmat),
  scale = Math.sqrt(jStat.chisquare.inv(level, 2)),
  maxLambdaI = indexOfMax(eig.lambda.x),
  minLambdaI = indexOfMin(eig.lambda.x),
  rx = stdDevX > stdDevY ? Math.sqrt(eig.lambda.x[maxLambdaI]) * scale : Math.sqrt(eig.lambda.x[minLambdaI]) * scale,
  ry = stdDevY > stdDevX ? Math.sqrt(eig.lambda.x[maxLambdaI]) * scale : Math.sqrt(eig.lambda.x[minLambdaI]) * scale,
  v1 = eig.E.x[maxLambdaI],
  theta = Math.atan2(v1[1], v1[0]) * 180 / Math.PI;

  if (theta < 0) {
    theta += 360;
  }
  //make the ellipse object
  errEllipse = {
    rx: rx,
    ry: ry,
    cx: center.x,
    cy: center.y,
    orient: -theta
  };

  return errEllipse;
};
```

The most obvious issue I see with the results of my current attempt is the ellipse is not fitting the data. It's been difficult to find exactly where I'm going wrong.

Can anyone show me:
1.) What's wrong with how I'm getting or plotting the radiuses and angle of the ellipse.
or 
2.) Any example of drawing error / confidence ellipses in javascript.

I’m using the libraries numericjs for the eigenvectors and values, jstat, and d3 for plotting.

[Here is a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8bONVq?p=preview) with the current code.

The errorEllipse function is in the “script.js” file.Test data can be changed by editing testData.js.

**Update:**

I'm adding the code for plotting the ellipse with d3 in case that is where the issue is:

```
svg.append('ellipse')
  .attr('class', 'q-ellipse-99')
  .attr('rx', Math.abs(xScale(xExtent[0] + ellipse99.rx) - xScale(xExtent[0])))
  .attr('ry', Math.abs(yScale(yExtent[0] + ellipse99.ry) - yScale(yExtent[0])))
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + xScale(ellipse99.cx) + ',' + yScale(ellipse99.cy) + ')rotate(' + ellipse99.orient + ')');
```

Both the xExtent and yExtent arrays are returned from calling d3.extent() on the data.

Comment: Fit is actually not bad at all. Everything seems okay, I think the reason why ellipsis don't fit the data are a bunch of outliers that you can see on the top-right.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Nearly forgot about this. I think it's ok too. Tested it with some other data. When initially posted I think the issue was on the d3 visualization side. Since then fixed the plnkr. Going to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original issue was that I didn't scale the ellipse's rx and ry values when plotting. Seems to work OK now with code above (under update).  Here is a [fork of plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/P08VeDSWMzLE7W52elkb?p=preview) that uses random normal test data (below) instead.

```
function genTestData(numPoints){
  var data = {x:[], y:[]};
  for(var i = 0; i < numPoints; i++){
    data.x[i] = jStat.normal.inv(Math.random(), 8.5, 2);
    data.y[i] = jStat.normal.inv(Math.random(), 6.5, 3);
    data.y[i] += data.x[i] * 2.1; //to test ellipse
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I did not get it, does it mean the function `errorEllipse` is correct?